# Use Ceedling / Rake for building a shared library and executable

Tags: makefile, rake, ceedling

I recently found Ceedling (https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Ceedling) , a nice rake based tool to build and unit test C projects. As I played a little with it I had a generally positive experience and thought that I might start my next C project with it.

However, it seems that ceedling is not capable (or undocumented in that respect) for building projects that consist of more than an executable or need specific compile flags. Do you know any example of a C project that uses Rake /Ceedling to build out shared libraries, configures LDFLAGS, CFLAGS and features several targets?

Answer (score 2):

The example project blinky shows you what you need to do to compile more advanced projects. You can get it by running `ceedling example blinky`. The project.yaml for it is as follows:

```
---
​
# Notes:
# This is a fully tested project that demonstrates the use
# of a timer ISR to blink the on board LED of an Arduino UNO
:project:
  :use_exceptions: FALSE
  :use_test_preprocessor: TRUE
  :use_auxiliary_dependencies: TRUE
  :build_root: build
  :release_build: TRUE
  :test_file_prefix: test_
​
#You'll have to specify these
:environment:
  - :mcu: atmega328p
  - :f_cpu: 16000000UL 
  - :serial_port: COM8  #change this to the serial port you are using!!!
  - :objcopy: avr-objcopy
  # Uncomment these lines if you are using windows and don't have these tools in your path
  # - :path:
    # - C:\mingw\bin
    # - C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin
    # - C:\WinAVR-20100110\utils\bin
    # - #{ENV['PATH']}
​
:extension:
  :executable: .bin
​
:release_build:
  :output: blinky
​
:paths:
  :test:
    - +:test/**
    - -:test/support
  :source:
    - src/**
  :support:
    - test/support
​
:defines:
  # in order to add common defines:
  #  1) remove the trailing [] from the :common: section
  #  2) add entries to the :common: section (e.g. :test: has TEST defined)
  :commmon: &common_defines []
  :test:
    - *common_defines
    - TEST
  :test_preprocess:
    - *common_defines
    - TEST
​
:tools:
  :release_compiler:
    :executable: avr-gcc
    :arguments:
      - ${1}
      - -DTARGET
      - -DF_CPU=#{ENV['F_CPU']}
      - -mmcu=#{ENV['MCU']}
      - -Iinclude/
      - -Wall
      - -Os
      - -c
      - -o ${2}
  :release_linker:
    :executable: avr-gcc
    :arguments:
      - -mmcu=#{ENV['MCU']}
      - ${1}
      - -o ${2}.bin
​
:cmock:
  :mock_prefix: mock_
  :when_no_prototypes: :warn
  :enforce_strict_ordering: TRUE
  :plugins:
    - :ignore
  :treat_as:
    uint8:    HEX8
    uint16:   HEX16
    uint32:   UINT32
    int8:     INT8
    bool:     UINT8
​
#:tools:
# Ceedling defaults to using gcc for compiling, linking, etc.
# As [:tools] is blank, gcc will be used (so long as it's in your system path)
# See documentation to configure a given toolchain for use
​
:plugins:
  :load_paths:
    - vendor/ceedling/plugins
  :enabled:
    - stdout_pretty_tests_report
    - module_generator
...
```

As you can see in the :tools: and :environment: section that you can do a lot to customize how you can compile a project and the exact settings/flags you want.

There [github docs](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Ceedling/blob/master/docs/CeedlingPacket.md) also talk about this more in depth and even gives walkthough a to show what certain settings in the :tools: options work as seen below:

Example [:tools] YAML blurbs

```
:tools:
  :test_compiler:
     :executable: compiler              #exists in system search path
     :name: 'acme test compiler'
     :arguments:
        - -I"$”: COLLECTION_PATHS_TEST_TOOLCHAIN_INCLUDE               #expands to -I search paths
        - -I"$”: COLLECTION_PATHS_TEST_SUPPORT_SOURCE_INCLUDE_VENDOR   #expands to -I search paths
        - -D$: COLLECTION_TEST_DEFINES  #expands to all -D defined symbols
        - --network-license             #simple command line argument
        - -optimize-level 4             #simple command line argument
        - "#{`args.exe -m acme.prj`}"   #in-line ruby sub to shell out & build string of arguments
        - -c ${1}                       #source code input file (Ruby method call param list sub)
        - -o ${2}                       #object file output (Ruby method call param list sub)
  :test_linker:
     :executable: /programs/acme/bin/linker.exe    #absolute file path
     :name: 'acme test linker'
     :arguments:
        - ${1}               #list of object files to link (Ruby method call param list sub)
        - -l$-lib:           #inline yaml array substitution to link in foo-lib and bar-lib
           - foo
           - bar
        - -o ${2}            #executable file output (Ruby method call param list sub)
  :test_fixture:
     :executable: tools/bin/acme_simulator.exe  #relative file path to command line simulator
     :name: 'acme test fixture'
     :stderr_redirect: :win                     #inform Ceedling what model of $stderr capture to use
     :arguments:
        - -mem large   #simple command line argument
        - -f "${1}"    #binary executable input file to simulator (Ruby method call param list sub)
```

Resulting command line constructions from preceding example [:tools] YAML blurbs

```
> compiler -I"/usr/include” -I”project/tests”
  -I"project/tests/support” -I”project/source” -I”project/include”
  -DTEST -DLONG_NAMES -network-license -optimize-level 4 arg-foo
  arg-bar arg-baz -c project/source/source.c -o
  build/tests/out/source.o
```